# Accessing Evernote in offline mode in Windows

Tags: evernote, evernote-app-notebook

Hi Iam creating an app in evernote and I want to create notes offine from my app if the app is not connected with the internet, so any api changes to be done or any changes to be done in settings can any help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Apparently I had some (very) old (and bad) information.  Evernote's Windows COM API has never been public or officially supported by Evernote ([link](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/31412-archived-free-siri-like-app-to-search-evernote-supports-andor-logic-at-the-same-time/?p=223326)).

for a local only API look at Evernote's documentation page for the Windows command line interface: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enscript.php

<strike>The Evernote SDK for Windows (link: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows) provides an API via COM which interacts with the Evernote application and not Evernote's cloud service.</strike>

If the user has set up the Evernote for Windows app on their computer you can access the data managed by the Evernote app on their windows device using the COM API (setup info here: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/tree/master/COM%20Setup) or via the command line: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enscript.php

Comment: I have  downloaded the Link given and install the EvernoteCom, but couldn't find the VBscript which support the offline mode and when I run the Sample app given in SDK got Exception  "Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMUserException' occurred in EDAM-win8.DLL" can you help me out how to resolve the Error

Comment: Evernote's API reference (including error codes) is here: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/

EDAMUserException indicates you should be able to resolve the issue yourself.  Did you receive a error code number as well?https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Errors.html#Struct_EDAMUserException

Comment: The VBscript API access Evernote through Evernote's cloud (i.e. through the internet) to access Evernote through the local app you'll need to use the command line interface (documentation link in answer) or use the COM interface (link to setup in answer).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have run the Evernote Com setup and included the necessary DLL files but when I run with the consumer key and secret key it is asking for authorization , I have import the EvernoteSDk refernces COMin my code stiil unable to send the note offline.

Comment: private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { string ="S=s1:U=912db:E=1562b07b76c:C=14ed3568a88:P=1cd:A=en-devtoken:V=2:H=0f3d0cba5fbd10ce5588bd72a7cd6717";
 greetingOutput.Text = "Hello, " + nameInput.Text + "!";
  string GUID = "ca5a57b8-04ab-4c6b-8bd6-191bf1d56b5e";
 EvernoteSDK.ENSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("vivek-agreeya", "3dc13516544c408b", "sandbox.evernote.com");
//EvernoteSDK.ENSession.SetSharedSessionDeveloperToken(devToken, "https://sandbox.evernote.com/shard/s1/notestore");{

Comment: EernoteSDK.ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();}EvernoteSDK.ENNote myPlainNote = new EvernoteSDK.ENNote(); );          myPlainNote.Title = "Testting";
            EvernoteSDK.ENNoteRef myPlainNoteRef = EvernoteSDK.ENSession.SharedSession.UploadNote(myPlainNote, null);

Comment: can you help me out the API so that i cant try it offline mode , I am stuck here